# mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (13)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

I have a CentOS 7 server with python-flask application which has worked flawlessly for the past 2 years.  I rebooted the server, and now I have an error that the flask app cannot access the MySQL (MariaDB really) db.  My database is accessible with PyCharm and DBeaver applications with no issues on 127.0.0.1:3306.  I have totally disabled any remote access.  I am not using Docker or an environment.  The script is configured to access the db using root.  There hasn't been any changes to the server in a long time.

Thank you in advance.  Any suggestions?

To resolve the issue, I re-installed the flask-mysqldb, turned off my firewall, and deleting the **pycache** folder.

Comment: Did you try to connect to the db with the CLI `mysql` ? you should try with the same OS user as your flask application, and same DB credentials (root).

Comment: Yes, it works fine. I can access my database via CLI and PyCharm with the same credentials.

Comment: Even though StackOverflow closed my question, the solution was SELinux was blocking Apache from access the MySQL db.  Check your sebool setting flag, or setsebool httpd_can_network_connect = 1.  Problem solved.